# selecting unique row from a table- ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table employee that has employee’s benefit data.
I have a field in the table called isenrolled if field is 1 that means employee has enrolled for benefit and if field is 0 that means not enrolled. 
My problem is i have multiple recs of a employee, that means Scott has two entries with isenrolled =1 and isenrolled =0. 
I want to select only one rec of SCOTT where his isenrolled =1 and reject the one where isenrolled =0, that way i will get only unique recs for employees who has enrolled and who has not enrolled. How do i select those employees? I tried the qry below and it doesn't work

```
select * FROM  employee e 
WHERE e.empid not IN( SELECT empid FROM employee  e2
WHERE e2.isenrolled =1)
```

Comment: please ignore the fist para, question starts from para2

Comment: @user525552: In that case, edit the question and remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I set up some test data using:

```
create table t4
as select * from scott.emp

alter table t4 add (isenrolled number(10))

update t4
set isenrolled = 0

insert into t4
(select emp.*, 1
from scott.emp)
```

At this point the t4 table has now two records for each employee (one where isenrolled = 0 and one where isenrolled = 1)
[image]

so I change ALLEN's data so he has "opted" out

```
delete from t4
where ename = 'ALLEN'
and isenrolled = 1
```

This query then shows the data for ALLEN (1 record) and SMITH (2 records)

```
select *
from t4
where ename IN ('ALLEN', 'SMITH')
order by ename
```

[image]

Then to show just one record per employee (restricted to ALLEN and SMITH in this case) you could use:

```
select t.*
from t4 t
where isenrolled = (select MAX(isenrolled)
                    from t4
                    where t4.empno = t.empno)
and ename IN ('ALLEN', 'SMITH')
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: suppose there are 2 select queries that are joined by union clause. and i want to select only those recs which are in unique in other words, i want to reject all the recs in second part of qry that appears in first part of qry, can i do that in uinion ? SELECT AS empid, '1' AS ISenrolled FROM employee emp, hrempusf usf where emp.employee = usf.employee and AND usf.field_key = 76 ---- 76 determines that employee has purchased stocks UNION ALL SELECT empid, '2' AS ISenrolled FROM employee emp;

Comment: CURSOR c_stock_option IS
Select empid, name, ssn, isenrolled
from employee 
where isenrolled=1

CURSOR c_espp_option IS
Select empid, name, ssn, isenrolled
from employee 
where isenrolled=2

Now i want to reject all the recs in second cursors that are in cursor 1 select, how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

select unique(e.empid) from employee e where e2.isenrolled =1

this will give you unique list of employees who are enrolled. Is that what you want to get?

Comment: I want list of all the employees that covers the ones who are enrolled and also the ones who are not enrolled.

Comment: I don't quite follow your logic. If Scott appears in both enrolled and not enrolled, Scott should appear twice. If you want a list of employees who are enrolled AND who are not enrolled a simple Select * from employee will do.

Comment: Or do you want a query where if the employee is enrolled, his not enrolled record should be ignored? In other words, enrolled=1 takes preference?

Comment: that is correct, 1 will take preferance over 0. that way i will get unique rec

Comment: suppose i have 2 recs of scott one with isenrolled=1 and one with isenrolled=0, and i have also other peoples recs who are not enrolled, so there isenrolled will be 0. I want to select everything and ignore any dups, so if scott has isenrolled=1 and isenrolled=2, i just want to display his rec where isenrolled=1.

Comment: i mean isenrolled=0 not isenrolled=2, sorry